# rysnc any file which has “_custom.conf” or just “_custom” in the filename

Tags: ssh, rsync, pattern-matching

Any way to rysync only files which feature _custom.conf or even just custom or *.conf in the filename?

I've had a play with

```
rsync -am --include='custom' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /etc/asterisk ~/backup
```

and

```
rsync -am --include='*custom*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /etc/asterisk ~/backup
```

and

```
rsync -am --include='*.conf' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /etc/asterisk ~/backup
```

but found they result in no output

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me

```
$ mkdir source
$ mkdir dest

$ cd source
$ touch a.conf  b.conf  b.noconf  custom  _custom.conf

$ ls
a.conf  b.conf  b.noconf  custom  _custom.conf


$ rsync -amv --include="custom" --include="*.conf" --exclude='*' ./ ../dest/
building file list ... done
./
_custom.conf
a.conf
b.conf
custom

sent 266 bytes  received 91 bytes  238.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ ls ../dest
a.conf  b.conf  custom  _custom.conf
```